# PhpStorm TSLint errors underline colour

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, tslint

Is there any way to change the colour of TSLint from red to another colour? Or some other way to make TSLint errors distinguishable from other errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In **File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | TypeScript**, select **TSLint**
- From the **Severity** dropdown, choose the desired severity level, or select **Edit severities** and set up your own severity level with desired highlighting

[image]

Note that you might need to re-open files to get the highlighting applied

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for.